# Is there any example of JMS implementaion with XA transactions with Solace

Tags: solace

I would like to find usefull example of JMS implementaion with XA transactions with Solace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solace JMS API contains a `XATransactions.java` example in the samples directory that shows how you can make use of XA transactions in your application.

Note that the sample code is manually managing the XA transaction by calling the relevant `XAResource` methods such as `XAResource.commit()`. XA transactions are usually used within Java EE application servers that contain a transaction manager to manage the lifecycle of 
XA transactions.