# com.solacesystems.jms.ConfigurationException: Invalid scheme "null" in host "null://x.x.x.x:x"

Tags: java, jms, xa, atomikos, solace

```
Caused by: com.solacesystems.jms.ConfigurationException: Invalid scheme "null" in host "null://x.x.x.x:x"
    at com.solacesystems.jms.SolConnection.<init>(SolConnection.java:142)
    at com.solacesystems.jms.SolConnection.<init>(SolConnection.java:79)
    at com.solacesystems.jms.SolXAConnection.<init>(SolXAConnection.java:20)
    at com.solacesystems.jms.SolXAConnectionFactoryImpl.createXAConnection(SolXAConnectionFactoryImpl.java:25)
    at com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsXAConnectionFactory.createPooledConnection(AtomikosJmsXAConnectionFactory.java:58)
```

How create valid scheme?

Comment: The issue was related with invalid configuration of  SolXAConnectionFactory. I've resolved it using suggested example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38656069/is-there-any-example-of-jms-implementaion-with-xa-transactions-with-solace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"null://x.x.x.x:x" is not a valid URL.

Valid URLs for Solace JMS are:

```
smf[s]://host:port
```

where the optional `s` uses SSL/TLS as secured transport. If `:port` is omitted, the protocol `smf` uses port `55555` and `smfs` uses port `55443`.